# ntpd keeps adding local servers while being told not to

Tags: debian, configuration, ntp

I'm configuring ntp inside a corporate network.

I've done

```
restrict default ignore
restrict -6 default ignore
```

and listed `server`s explicitly (I'm using public servers from `pool.ntp.org`). I also didn't enable `broadcastclient`.

After a while, `ntpq -p` keeps showing only a particular server inside the local network that I did not add in the configuration file.

Shouldn't `restrict default ignore` make ntpd ignore all packets from servers not explicitly mentioned?

I've checked the servers I'm using with `dig`, and the addresses seem correct.

Here's `ntpq -pn`:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 10.200.10.253   .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

And my current `ntp.conf` (comments removed)

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 2.europe.pool.ntp.org

restrict default ignore
restrict -6 default ignore
restrict 2.europe.pool.ntp.org nomodify
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste into your **question** the output of `ntpq -pn`?  It'd be helpful to see your `/ntp.conf` in its entirety, too.

Comment: @MadHatter edited to add those two.

Comment: Are there any ntp related entries in /etc/hosts?  If you ping instead of dig, do you get the same results for your server entry?  Is it always that same 10.x address?

Comment: @Aaron A couple of entries there, but nothing NTP related, and not this host in particular - which, yes, it's always the same.

Comment: Do you have other servers on the same vlan that are able to reach 2.europe.pool.ntp.org?  My next step would be to stop ntpd, start tcpdump and capture all traffic just in case something is doing proxy arp or some other form of redirection, then start ntpd.

Comment: @Aaron I just verified I *am*, in fact, able to reach `2.europe.pool.ntp.org` using `ntpdate`. I've just found the problem, I was misunderstanding the way ntp worked on this particular system. will post an answer briefly

Answer (score 8):

After some debugging and `Aaron`'s help, I've found the problem.

**The ISC DHCP client fetches ntp servers information by default in Debian.**

Debian's `ntpd` init script makes it use that info, by extending `/etc/ntp.conf` with it. The resulting file is made available at `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp`.

The solution is, of course, properly configuring DHCP not to receive ntp servers (just remove the `ntp-servers` option in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`).

More information available in [NTP's support page, section 6.12](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringNTP#Section_6.12.):

```
ISC's dhcp is able to automatically configure the servers used by ntpd. 
Here's how to get it working:

    The dhcp server you are using must be configured to provide 
    the ntp-servers option

    Configure your dhclient to request ntp-servers (it doesn't by default). 
    To do this add ntp-servers to the default request line in 
    /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

    Create an /etc/ntp.conf with all of the other settings that you wish to use. 
    This file will be used to create /etc/ntp.conf.dhcp, it won't be over written.

    Your ntpd must be told to use /etc/ntp.conf.dhcp if it exists. 
    This is usually accomplished in the ntp init script (e.g. /etc/init.d/ntp).
```